# Fill In Missing Values With Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, missing-data

I'm trying to `fill in` missing values after `groupby` two columns on the `planets` dataset.

```
# Load data
df = sns.load_dataset('planets')

# Check naan
df.isna().sum()

method              0
number              0
orbital_period     43
mass              522
distance          227
year                0
dtype: int64
```

However, after filling in the missing values with group mean, missing values still remain. I'm not sure why this is happening (I tried this on the `titanic` dataset and it completely works there)). Even if I try to fill by each column (no for loop), the problem still shows up.

```
# Select naan column names
null_cols = df.columns[df.isnull().any()]

# Fill in with loop
for col in null_cols:
  df[col] = df.groupby(['method', 'year'])[col].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))

# Check naan values again
df.isna().sum()

method              0
number              0
orbital_period     28
mass              405
distance           26
year                0
```

What's wrong here? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The reason this is happening is that all of the values for some of the groups you're generating do not have a single non-nan value.**

Take the value/col `mass` for the group `('Microlensing', 2012)` it has 6 entries of which there are 0 non-nan values. If there are no actual values to take the mean of you can't really calculate a mean which can be used for imputing the other nan-values in the same group.

Here is the debug code I used:

```py
import math
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset("planets")

print(df.isna().sum())

null_cols = df.columns[df.isnull().any()]


def inspect_fillna(x):
    mean_x = x.mean()
    if math.isnan(mean_x):
        print("group=", x.name, ", entries=", len(x), ", all_are_nan=", len(x) == x.isna().sum(), sep="")
    imputed_x = x.fillna(mean_x)
    return imputed_x


for col in null_cols:
    print("\n\ncol=", col, sep="")
    df[col] = df.groupby(["method", "year"])[col].transform(lambda x: inspect_fillna(x))

print(df.isna().sum())
```

Here is the output:

```
method              0
number              0
orbital_period     43
mass              522
distance          227
year                0
dtype: int64


col=orbital_period
group=('Imaging', 2004), entries=3, all_are_nan=True
group=('Imaging', 2005), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Imaging', 2007), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Imaging', 2012), entries=2, all_are_nan=True
group=('Imaging', 2013), entries=7, all_are_nan=True
group=('Microlensing', 2004), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Microlensing', 2009), entries=2, all_are_nan=True
group=('Microlensing', 2012), entries=6, all_are_nan=True
group=('Microlensing', 2013), entries=4, all_are_nan=True
group=('Transit Timing Variations', 2014), entries=1, all_are_nan=True


col=mass
group=('Astrometry', 2010), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Astrometry', 2013), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Eclipse Timing Variations', 2008), entries=2, all_are_nan=True
group=('Eclipse Timing Variations', 2010), entries=2, all_are_nan=True
group=('Eclipse Timing Variations', 2011), entries=3, all_are_nan=True
group=('Imaging', 2004), entries=3, all_are_nan=True
group=('Imaging', 2005), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Imaging', 2006), entries=4, all_are_nan=True
group=('Imaging', 2007), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Imaging', 2008), entries=8, all_are_nan=True
group=('Imaging', 2009), entries=3, all_are_nan=True
group=('Imaging', 2010), entries=6, all_are_nan=True
group=('Imaging', 2011), entries=3, all_are_nan=True
group=('Imaging', 2012), entries=2, all_are_nan=True
group=('Imaging', 2013), entries=7, all_are_nan=True
group=('Microlensing', 2004), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Microlensing', 2005), entries=2, all_are_nan=True
group=('Microlensing', 2006), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Microlensing', 2008), entries=4, all_are_nan=True
group=('Microlensing', 2009), entries=2, all_are_nan=True
group=('Microlensing', 2010), entries=2, all_are_nan=True
group=('Microlensing', 2011), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Microlensing', 2012), entries=6, all_are_nan=True
group=('Microlensing', 2013), entries=4, all_are_nan=True
group=('Orbital Brightness Modulation', 2011), entries=2, all_are_nan=True
group=('Orbital Brightness Modulation', 2013), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Pulsar Timing', 1992), entries=2, all_are_nan=True
group=('Pulsar Timing', 1994), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Pulsar Timing', 2003), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Pulsar Timing', 2011), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Pulsation Timing Variations', 2007), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Transit', 2002), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Transit', 2004), entries=5, all_are_nan=True
group=('Transit', 2006), entries=5, all_are_nan=True
group=('Transit', 2007), entries=16, all_are_nan=True
group=('Transit', 2008), entries=17, all_are_nan=True
group=('Transit', 2009), entries=18, all_are_nan=True
group=('Transit', 2010), entries=48, all_are_nan=True
group=('Transit', 2011), entries=80, all_are_nan=True
group=('Transit', 2012), entries=92, all_are_nan=True
group=('Transit', 2014), entries=40, all_are_nan=True
group=('Transit Timing Variations', 2011), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Transit Timing Variations', 2012), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Transit Timing Variations', 2013), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Transit Timing Variations', 2014), entries=1, all_are_nan=True


col=distance
group=('Eclipse Timing Variations', 2009), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Eclipse Timing Variations', 2011), entries=3, all_are_nan=True
group=('Eclipse Timing Variations', 2012), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Microlensing', 2004), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Microlensing', 2005), entries=2, all_are_nan=True
group=('Microlensing', 2006), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Microlensing', 2008), entries=4, all_are_nan=True
group=('Microlensing', 2009), entries=2, all_are_nan=True
group=('Microlensing', 2010), entries=2, all_are_nan=True
group=('Microlensing', 2011), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Orbital Brightness Modulation', 2013), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Pulsar Timing', 1992), entries=2, all_are_nan=True
group=('Pulsar Timing', 1994), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Pulsar Timing', 2003), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Pulsation Timing Variations', 2007), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Transit', 2002), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
group=('Transit Timing Variations', 2014), entries=1, all_are_nan=True
method              0
number              0
orbital_period     28
mass              405
distance           26
year                0
dtype: int64
```

**Possible solution**: Consider making your groups larger by removing `year` or `method` from your group.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
df.fillna(df.groupby(['method', 'year'])[col].transform('mean'))
```

Comment: Hi @rhug123 -- It doesn't fill in the missing values. Would you please check -- `df.fillna(df.groupby(['method', 'year'])['mass'].transform('mean')).isnull().sum()`

Comment: if you are passing one column (mass) into transform, it will provide a series. If you wish to do this for one column only, fillna can accept a dictionary. Try `df.fillna({'mass':df.groupby(['method', 'year'])['mass'].transform('mean')}).isnull().sum()`

Comment: Sorry @rhug123. It still doesn't work